# Saving the defaultive value of a static int over a class - java

Tags: java

Say I have a Class that contains this code:

```
private static int sum = 0;

public static int t1(){
    sum += 2;
    return sum;
}

public static int t2(){
    sum += 5;
    return sum;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(t1());
    System.out.println(t2());
}
```

The returned values will be:
2
7

What I want to do is to keep the `static int sum` as its defaultive value (0) each time I finish a method (from t1 to t2 it will be changed to 0).
that means something like `return sum-- (sum times so it will be changed to 0)`, or any other easy solution.
the returned values should be:

2
 5

Comment: I know that will work but i need a more efficiant solution if possible because I have a lot of methods that use the variable sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't update the field:

```
public static int t1(){
    return sum + 2;
}

public static int t2(){
    return sum + 5;
}
```

Comment: The Smart way!!

Comment: hmmm, in my whole project I use the sum in a for loop so I will need to use sum += "value" then return the sum, so is there a better solution?

Comment: @PriyaJain Not trying to delegitimize the answer, but there is hardly anything deserving of being called "smart" here... It's just common-sense (which is ever more uncommon, each passing day)

Comment: Make local variables, don't use a static variable.  Using `sum` in the way you're trying to use it reflects a design problem.

Comment: @AlmightyR I guess Smart way is the rare way of doing things. In that case it matches the definition of common sense too :) Sometime we forget that things can be done in a easy way too!!

Comment: @AbdallahBarghouti Then you're using the wrong design for this. You can't have both 1) The value stay default. and 2) The value *not* stay default. at the same time without some hackery. I'd recommend changing the design so that this hackery isn't needed. --- By the available information, seems like bad responsibility-delegation (your static class is being responsible for something it shouldn't) --- In other words, pretty much what Louis said...

Comment: @PriyaJain That's not a "rare way of doing" this... It should be the first solution that comes to mind[?]... /*AlmightyR starts to despair over the possibility that common-sense is now so rare that even something so common-sensical is no longer common-sense to the average programmer/*

Comment: Common sense also tells that 2 people can have different perspective and people should not judge on that basis. If I find something smart that may or may not be smart according to you. Also sometime great people neglect the most common things so I think an average programmer has the liberty to vote as per his/her choice ;)

Comment: @PriyaJain I don't remember telling anyone that they couldn't think the answer is smart, or that they couldn't vote on it however they see fit. All I said is that, in my opinion, it is not particularly smart, and it is, or should be, just common-sense for any non-novice programmer to approach the solution this way. =)

Answer (score 0):

since the field is not final, you can also reset it between the 2 calls. Although, I think not updating it at all is a better option.

Comment: How to reset it between the calls? adding sum = 0 between the methods wont work

Comment: @AbdallahBarghouti Well that would depend on what the criteria is. You mentioned that you needed the output to be 2 __ 5 for the two calls. One way is to reset the value. Unless we know more about your code, we can't tell you why sum = 0 will or won't work.

Comment: for this code, if I add sum = 0 between methods as it is it wont work, that's what I mean.

Comment: Then you should be using local variables instead of using static variables. Static variables are 1 per class and all instances have access to the variable which can lead to issues.